# Can't make object reload in chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, object, reload

i replace a iframe with a object in my website and i use jquery to reload/refresh the object to show new content, only problem is that my code do not work with chrome browser ! Code is working in firefox and ie and i try to not use iframe because chrome keep caching old page .

Here is the object code :

```
<object id="safari_window" name="safari_window" type="text/html" data="index.html" onload="fixWebSite()" ><p>Your browser do not support object tag</p></object>
```

here is the jquery code :

```
$('dd ul li').click(function(){
        $.post("editor_func.php", { menu: $(this).attr('id'), d: $('#d').val(),}, function(){
            $('#safari_window').attr('data', function ( i, val ) { return val; });
        });
    })
```

Thanks for helping !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using

```
function ( i, val ) { return val.split('?')[0] + '?' + (new Date()).getTime() });
```

if the problem is caching.. (*you can use the same logic for iframes..*)

Comment: Not solving object problem but solving iframe problem thanks !